# Android action bar theme not applying

Tags: android, android-layout

I've recently started android development and it's generally went on without a problem. However, I cannot seem to apply a theme to the action bar despite following guides/instructions to the letter (or so I can tell).

I've generated my theme using the Android Action Bar Style Generator, added the res folder to my project and edited the manifest file to use the new theme. I've got a the style in both values and values-v14 with the latter using "android:".

**Desired results** vs **current results**:

[image] [image] [image]

res/values/styles_amulettheme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- File created by the Android Action Bar Style Generator

         Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
         Copyright (C) 2012 readyState Software Ltd

         Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
         you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
         You may obtain a copy of the License at

              http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

         Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
         distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
         WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
         See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
         limitations under the License.
    -->

    <resources>

        <style name="Theme.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_amulettheme</item>
            <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Amulettheme</item>
            <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Amulettheme</item>
            <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Amulettheme</item>
            <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Amulettheme</item>
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Amulettheme</item>
            <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_amulettheme</item>
            <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_amulettheme</item>
            <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Amulettheme</item>

                    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
            <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Amulettheme.Widget</item>

        </style>

        <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
            <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_amulettheme</item>
            <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_amulettheme</item>
            <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_amulettheme</item>
            <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Amulettheme</item>
        </style>

        <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
            <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_amulettheme</item>
            <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Amulettheme</item>
        </style>

        <style name="PopupMenu.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu"> 
            <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_amulettheme</item>   
        </style>

        <style name="DropDownListView.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
            <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_amulettheme</item>
        </style>

        <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_amulettheme</item>
        </style>

        <style name="DropDownNav.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_amulettheme</item>
            <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_amulettheme</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_amulettheme</item>
        </style>

        <style name="ProgressBar.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
            <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_amulettheme</item>
        </style>

        <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_amulettheme</item>
        </style>

        <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
        <style name="Theme.Amulettheme.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Amulettheme</item>
            <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Amulettheme</item>
        </style>

    </resources>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="quinn.anth.amulet"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Amulettheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="quinn.anth.amulet.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Managed to fix it thanks for all your help. I had some misnamed images so the wrong one was being used when pressed. The focused/clicked items were listed under selectable_background_amulettheme.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last picture, you need to use `itemBackground` attribute in your parent style as follows:

```
<style name="Theme.Amulettheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/item_background</item>
</style>
```

Let me know if this resolve your issue.

Comment: This has solved one of my issues, however how would I go about changing the colour of the clicked/focused item instead of changing all of the backgrounds?

Comment: I don't understand clearly your issues, you should list them. To change the color clicked/focused, I don't know if this is possible from the style. However, I thought about a workaround in onOptionsItemSelected to change the icon with its id.. @AnthonyQuinn

Answer (score 0):

If your using Android Support library .. for device with Android < 3.0 version.
You should use action bar background name as `background` and other higher version as `android:background`

Change your custom theme like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/Blue</item>
    <item name="background">@color/Blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I've got two copies on the style, one using android: for 3+ and one with just the variable name for previous versions. I've now managed to change the colour of the action bar but still cannot find why the accents (click and focus) aren't working. If I select an item from the action bar the button turns grey instead of the desired orange/gold.